# Bad received data C#

Tags: c#, server

why I received this:[received string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEfkM.jpg), when I send this?[sended string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPpKn.jpg)

**Cod of client app:**

```
try
        {

            tcpclient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 80);

            String str = "LOG" + Login.Text + "$" + hasło.Text;
            Stream stm = tcpclient.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = asen.GetBytes(str);
            stm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

**Cod of host:**

```
  try
        {
            string msg = "";
            Socket socket = Listerner.AcceptSocket();
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();

            int x = socket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            byte[] buffor = new byte[x];
            int data = socket.Receive(buffor);
            string wiadomość = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffor);
```

Comment: Because `socket.RecieveBufferSize` is the size of the buffer, not the size of the data. `int data` is the number of bytes you received, which can be as high as the `ReceiveBufferSize`, but in this case it is lower and the size you should use for your byte array. If there are more bytes sent then fits in the buffer, you should read again until `int data` is 0.

Comment: Please paste the sent and received strings as text, not pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `buffor` variable at the host has a fixed size and thus `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` will try to convert the complete byte array back to a string, regardless how many bytes were actually received.

`socket.Receive` returns the number of bytes that were actually received. Use this information to restore the string:

```
int bytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffor);
string wiadomość = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffor, 0, bytesReceived);
```

See [Encoding.ASCII.GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8#-berl-dt) and [Socket.Receive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Receive_System_Byte___) for reference.

Now it should work for your tiny example. But be aware that you might receive more bytes than your buffer can take at once. So you have to do something like:

```
string messageReceived = "";
int bytesReceived = 0;
do
{
    bytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffor)
    messageReceived += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffor, 0, bytesReceived);
} while(bytesReceived >= buffor.Length)
// now messageReceived should contain the whole text
```

Comment: Thanks the first solution works, but when manually how to try the second one then it freeze my server.

Comment: But i have other problem, why if in list I have user(ala, ala) i received false if use this same??
https://imgur.com/a/WJOfcXo
     if (Users.Contains(new Userspasword(login, password)))

Comment: My first solution blocks because Receive is a blocking call. What's the best for you really depends on the requirements and the design of your host program. Should the host keep the connection open until next data is received? Will the client close the connection? But that would lead far beyond your question and thus should be discussed in another question. I adapted the code so it should no longer freeze. Also for your next question in your comment you should create a new question. This is not a forum here. One Question - One Answer.

Comment: Ok, like end to end point. Closed after received respons. I can't send new question.

Comment: Like something I dealt with the list, I used Exist because I don't know why Contains returned false, but this work. 
If (Users.Exists(x => x.RegisteredUser == login && x.Pasword == password)){return true}